# Python: Multiple keys with same values (mutable type). Changing one of these values updates the other values too. How do I avoid this?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
incident_data_dict = {}
for cause in causes_dict:
    if driver in incident_data_dict or vehicle in incident_data_dict:
        incident_data_dict[driver][cause] += causes_dict[cause]
        incident_data_dict[vehicle][cause] += causes_dict[cause]
    else:
        incident_data_dict.update({driver: causes_dict})
        incident_data_dict.update({vehicle: causes_dict})
```

> incident_data_dict = {u'Vehicle_1': {'Over Speeding': 0, 'Over
>   Acceleration': 2, 'Hard Braking': 0}, u'Driver_1': {'Over Speeding':
>   0, 'Over Acceleration': 2, 'Hard Braking': 0}}

Reference map

> u'Vehicle_1' *(103072304)* = {dict} {'Over Speeding': 0, 'Over
>   Acceleration': 2, 'Hard Braking': 0}   'Hard Braking' **(107104320)**
>   = {int} 0   'Over Acceleration' **(107104360)** = {int} 2   'Over Speeding' **(107104680)** = {int} 0
>
> u'Driver_1' *(103088424)* = {dict} {'Over Speeding': 0, 'Over
>   Acceleration': 2, 'Hard Braking': 0}   'Hard Braking' **(107104320)**
>   = {int} 0   'Over Acceleration' **(107104360)** = {int} 2   'Over Speeding' **(107104680)** = {int} 0

Updating incident_data_dict[driver] like so:
incident_data_dict[driver][cause] += causes_dict[cause] 
updates 'cause' key in incident_data_dict[vehicle] too, and this is because all the 'cause' keys have same reference. This increments those keys twice instead of once. 
How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a deepcopy of the dictionary

```
import copy
incident_data_dict2=copy.deepcopy(incident_data_dict)
#both dictionaries are independent
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked :)
Unfortunately, my reputation is less than 15 and my upvote doesn't get displayed. Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't matter. :)